# Pass (password manager) taking a long time to request master password

Tags: password, gpg, password-store

I have two arch linux machines: desktop & laptop;
Both have [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) as the password manager, with the same gpg key, versions, passwords;
but when asking for password on the laptop popup that asks for master key is instantaneous,
while desktop can take up to a minute. Any ideas?

```
$ time pass 10fastfingers.com
*********
pass 10fastfingers.com  0.02s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 28.751 total

$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.32
libgcrypt 1.9.4-unknown
...
```

Comment: The speed issue may not be directly related to the pass command.  On your desktop, have you ran other commands and timed them?  Am I safe to assume your desktop is at least a recent CPU with recent storage?  Try a simple `hdparm -Tt /dev/sdaX` where sdaX is the same device where you have the pass git repo stored.

Comment: I don't think that is the case; the desktop has better hardware than the laptop (by a lot). Also the masterkey popup itself wasn't so slow at the fresh install, but became like that at some point -_-  

`$ doas hdparm -Tt /dev/sda3`
`/dev/sda3:`
`Timing cached reads:   20130 MB in  2.00 seconds = 10079.40 MB/sec`
`Timing buffered disk reads: 1078 MB in  3.00 seconds = 359.04 MB/sec`

Comment: Those are perfectly acceptable numbers for storage speed.  Ah, I did not see in your original post that the fresh install speed for pass was fast.  Then I would work backwards and check if you installed any new packages since pass was installed.  If so, and if possible, uninstall or roll back those packages and try pass again.  Did you install pass using pacman, source or another package manager?